# disable external url links in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I used some open resource to handle my external links in WebView, so right now every time I click the url a new view would show the page with "Done" "back" "forward" "open link in safari" something like that. But at the same time the earlier webview of my app is still loading and show the url website. How could I stop it? When the user click Done for the new page, definitely they want to go back to the earlier page.
here is the open resource class I used : https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController

Thanks. wish I made myself clear. I'm new here, and also new to ios development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you're asking but every time a link is clicked in a UIWebView, the UIWebView delegate shouldStartLoadWithRequest method gets called.

If you don't want the link to load you simply return NO from this method.

There are also properties in the UIWebView class to enable you to go back or go forward through the page history.

If that doesn't answer your question, can you try and rephrase it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response, you are right that I didn't return NO in shouldStartLoadWithRequest section. I just want to stop the original view from loading links when I click them cause I would have a new view to handle them.